# Log a successful uninstall with a BAT file

Tags: batch-file, logging, uninstallation

I have created a BAT file to uninstall any version of skype. It works fine. I am wanting to set it up to also check the event viewer to see that it uninstalled successfully. I was wondering if there was anyone that has done something to this nature. So far, this is what I have:

```
@echo off
echo Closing skype...
taskkill /F /IM Skype.exe
echo Removing previous versions...
wmic product where "Name like 'Skype%%'" call uninstall
```

New Code:

```
@ECHO off

IF EXSIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype" GOTO INSTALLED
ELSE IF EXSIST "C:\Program Files\Skype" GOTO INSTALLED
ELSE GOTO NOTINSTALLED

:Installed
taskkill /F /IM skype.exe
wmic product where "name like 'Skype%%'" call uninstall
shutdown /r /f

:NOTINSTALLED
EXIT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `%errorlevel%` variable to get the last error code.

If it's 0, then it worked!

```
if %errorlevel%==0 echo Uninstall successful
```

EDIT:

An update for your new code, (you can't do an `else if` in batch, only use them individually)

```
@ECHO off
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype" GOTO INSTALLED
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Skype" GOTO INSTALLED
EXIT

:INSTALLED
taskkill /F /IM skype.exe
wmic product where "name like 'Skype%%'" call uninstall
shutdown /r /f
```

Comment: Thanks, I am looking to make an if else statement to finalize the process but the closest i could get was 2 if statements but it doesnt do the reboot regardless of which order I do them in. I want it to restart if the uninstall was successful, and to basically force out the errorlevel to the basically state that the batch file errored out even though it successfully ran the command because the software we are using to push it out keeps seeing it as a success even if it doesnt remove anything.
`If %errorlevel% == '0' (shutdown /r /f)
If not %errorlevel% == '0' (Exit %errorlevel%)`

Comment: Please forgive my code formatting, i was trying to get it block it off correctly, but being new to posting on this site, couldnt get it to work. it should be 2 lines.

Comment: @KevinHogan No worries, can you do another check to confirm the uninstall, i.e. the program folder being deleted, if you aren't getting a useful error code?

Comment: I looked and it is uninstalled, with those 2 if statements, it doesn't reboot, regardless of if it successfully uninstalled. Basically we are pushing out this to people that have skype that we dont want to have it, and want the system to reboot if it uninstalls successfully, but to pass back an error code back to the software that is pushing it out. Right now, it reads that the bat file runs successfully, even if it doesnt uninstall

Comment: Have you tried setting the shutdown timeout? If you don't it's 30 secs by default. i.e. `shutdown /r /t 0 /f`

Comment: If this doesn't work, any chance you could post the complete code of your shutdown method?

Comment: `@echo off`

`echo Closing Skype`
`taskkill /F /IM skype.exe`

`echo Removing previous versions...`
`wmic product where "name like 'Skype%%'" call uninstall`

`If %errorlevel% == '0' (shutdown /r /f)`
`If not %errorlevel% == '0' (Exit %errorlevel%)` this is what i am running so far (each code block is a new line.) It runs without error, but returns that the bat file was successful even if it didnt uninstall anything and it also doesnt reboot regardless of if it uninstalls anything or not

Comment: I've done some testing, and it looks like the errorlevel comparison is the problem, try without quotes as it's coming back false when comparing to 0 `if %errorlevel%==0 (shutdown)`

Comment: I just tried that, it did cause it to reboot, but it did it even though it didnt uninstall anything, is there a way to get this to not reboot if it doesnt uninstall anything?

Comment: I was thinking, you first check to see if the folder `C:\Program Files\Skype` exists, if it does, attempt the uninstall and reboot, if it doesn't then don't do anything. It's the best thing I can think of without getting any error codes

Comment: `@ECHO off`

`IF EXSIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype" GOTO INSTALLED`
`ELSE IF EXSIST "C:\Program Files\Skype" GOTO INSTALLED`
`ELSE GOTO NOTINSTALLED`

`:Installed`
`taskkill /F /IM skype.exe`
`wmic product where "name like 'Skype%%'" call uninstall`
`shutdown /r /f`

`:NOTINSTALLED`
`EXIT`

I think I am missing something in there. When I run it like this it says "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype" was unexpected at this time

Comment: It's probably a line break issue, could you post it in your question so I can see the formatting, as it doesn't show in the comments?

Comment: Strange, it still tells me "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype" was unexpected at this time

Comment: It works ok for me, try escaping the closing bracket, `C:\Program Files (x86^)\Skype`

Comment: Ok, I got it, noticed a fat finger on the word exist. Apparently there isnt 2 S in that word, haha, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
(
echo.Exit code was %errorlevel%
echo.
echo.Uninstall application terminated on %date% - %time%
) > ".\uninstall_log.txt"
```

If you want to output to console then use this:

```
echo.
echo.
echo.Exit code was %errorlevel%
echo.
echo.Uninstall application terminated on %date% - %time%
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.Press any key to exit Skype uninstaller.
pause>nul
exit
```

Comment: Thanks, this is another great option to know of.